# Current user information is displaying on all profiles Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am making a Social media website where user join events and compete against each other.

Each time a user join an event a status appears on his profile. The issue is that when I look at other user profiles, the statuses just match who ever the current user is.

If someone could help me write some code that shows the different statuses for each of the users that would be great. I know the question may sound a little vague.

I just need to know a way to see only post based on which profile I am viewing not the current user. Thanks!

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <% if !@user_events.present? %>
          <h4>Hi <%= User.find_by_username(params[:id]).username %>, thanks for joining!</h4>
          <h4>Join events, complete them, and compete</h4>
        <% end %>

        <% @user_events.each do |ue|%>
          <% if ue.event.present? %>
            <h4 class="blue">
              <%= User.find_by_username(params[:id]).username %>
            </h4>
            <% userevent = User.find_by(params[:event]) %>
            <p>I'm going to <%= link_to ue.event.title %>.</p>
            <% if ue.hours.present? %>
              <h5> Completed Hours: <%= ue.hours %>   </h5>
            <% end %>
            <% if ue.hours.present? %>
              <img src="#" style="width: 10%;" alt="">
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the controller?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's very bad to have queries to the database inside of your view. Please, move expression inside `<%= User.find_by_username(params[:id]).username %>` to your controller and then use instance variable to show username.

It would be great if you provide your controller code too. I guess you should pick user events depending on the user you found by params[:id].

Answer (score 0):

Without the controller, it is a bit hard to help. But I would suggest trying something on the user controller like

```
def get_status_by_user
  user_id = params[:user_id]
  user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
  user.event
end
```

where the `params[user_id]` is the id of hte user you want to get the event.

Also what I can see is `<% userevent = User.find_by(params[:event]) %>` you do not specify a user so the method will return the last one

> Finds the first record matching the specified conditions.

[Find_by docuemntaion](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

So if you want to keep your code mostly as it is you need to first find the user you want to get the event and then get the status for that specific user

Also giving a little information on the DB schema could help